# Issue with cordova calendar plugin only for Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am facing issue with ionic calendar plugin
Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a recurring event for example 1st May to 21st May
2. Delete the event on 7th and 8th of May.
   Issue: All the events are getting deleted from calendar when i go to native calendar and check this.

This issue only happens with Android.
Could someone help me out in this.